# Change string word order in a file

Tags: python, python-2.7, biopython

I have a file with this kind of strings:

```
gene_1  1   181 +   1   01  15.2689 b   -   -   -
gene_2  220 300 -   0   01  0.649993    b   -   -   -
gene_1  1   295 -   0   10  16.1465 b   -   -   -
gene_1  39  278 +   0   11  13.4122 b   28  33  -0.698805
gene_1  1   133 -   0   10  13.9421 p   139 144 0.493777
```

I need to change the fourth column (the column with + and -) within the fifth (0 and 1) to obtain the next:

```
gene_1  1   181 1   +   01  15.2689 b   -   -   -
gene_2  220 300 0   -   01  0.649993    b   -   -   -
gene_1  1   295 0   -   10  16.1465 b   -   -   -
gene_1  39  278 0   +   11  13.4122 b   28  33  -0.698805
gene_1  1   133 0   -   10  13.9421 p   139 144 0.493777
```

any ideas?

Comment: Where is your code and what exactly is the problem with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could read the file by string, and split each line by space:

```
your_rearranged_lines = []

with open("yourFile") as file:
    for line in file:
        splitLine = line.split()
        # stores the first three tokens as normal, switches the fourth and fifth,
        # and stores the remaining tokens as normal
        rearranged_line = splitLine[0:4] + splitLine[4] + splitLine[3] + splitLine[4:]
        your_rearranged_lines.append(rearranged_line)
```

Substantively, this code uses python's [slicing syntax](http://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-listsarrays-and-tuples-in-python/). This assumes two things based on your example above:

1. That your file does not have any tokens with necessary spaces within them (e.g. "gene 56")
2. That your file (counting each dash as a token) has at least five tokens in each line.

If the former isn't true, you'll split up tokens that should be taken as a single item, and if the latter isn't true, you'll encounter an out of range exception.